# Assign multiple ID to name

Tags: r

I am trying to wired merge. I have a dataset `df` and correspondent ID list `ID`

```
ID <- data.frame(Alphabet = c("A", "A","A","B", "B", "C"), 
             Value = c(101,102, 103,201,202,301))

df <-  data.frame(Name = c("A", "A","B", "C"))
```

I want to merge/ assign IDs to `df`
And get a df looks like

```
Name   ID1  ID2 ID3
A      101  102 103
A      101  102 103
B      201  202
C      301
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ? Notice the missing value using `NA` is better than blank ~

If do want `''` rather than `NA` just using `outdf[is.na(outdf)]=''`

```
library(dplyr)
ID=ID%>%group_by(Alphabet)%>%mutate(ID=row_number())
library(reshape2)
DF=as.data.frame(acast(ID, Alphabet~ID, value.var="Value"))
DF$Name=row.names(DF)
merge(df,DF,by='Name')


  Name   1   2   3
1    A 101 102 103
2    A 101 102 103
3    B 201 202  NA
4    C 301  NA  NA
```

or using `tidyr`(Recommend~ Cause you are working with `data.frame`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
ID=ID%>%group_by(Alphabet)%>%mutate(id=row_number())
DF=spread(ID, id,Value)
merge(df,DF,by.x='Name',by.y='Alphabet')

  Name   1   2   3
1    A 101 102 103
2    A 101 102 103
3    B 201 202  NA
4    C 301  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I would address this problem by preparing a list that includes the rows of your final data frame and then 'rbinding' them together. The only trick is to count the max length of your rows and add NAs accordingly. This should work.

```
ID <- data.frame(Alphabet = c("A", "A","A","B", "B", "C"), 
                 Value = c(101,102, 103,201,202,301))

df <-  data.frame(Name = c("A", "A","B", "C"))


tmp <- lapply(df$Name, (function(id){
  ID[ID$Alphabet == id, ]$Value
}))
max.el <- max(sapply(tmp, length))
out.df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(tmp, (function(el){
  len.na <- max.el - length(el) 
  c(el, rep(NA, len.na))  
})))

print(out.df, na.print = "")
```

This is the result

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  101  102  103
[2,]  101  102  103
[3,]  201  202     
[4,]  301
```

If showing NAs is not a problem, then

```
colnames(out.df) <- paste("ID", c(1:max.el), sep = "")
out.df <- cbind(df, out.df)
out.df

  Name ID1 ID2 ID3
1    A 101 102 103
2    A 101 102 103
3    B 201 202  NA
4    C 301  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a solution using `dcast()` from the `data.table` package to reshape from long to wide format and a *right join*:

```
library(data.table)
# coerce to data.table
setDT(D)[
  # reshape from long to wide, thereby creating column names
  , dcast(.SD, Alphabet ~ rowid(Alphabet, prefix = "ID"))][
    # rename column
    , setnames(.SD, "Alphabet", "Name")][
      # right join with df to repeat rows
      setDT(df), on = "Name"]
```

> ```
>    Name ID1 ID2 ID3
> 1:    A 101 102 103
> 2:    A 101 102 103
> 3:    B 201 202  NA
> 4:    C 301  NA  NA
> ```

In case `NA` must not be shown, the output needs to be converted to type character:

```
setDT(D)[, dcast(.SD, Alphabet ~ rowid(Alphabet, prefix = "ID"), as.character, fill = "")][
    , setnames(.SD, "Alphabet", "Name")][
      setDT(df), on = "Name"]
```

> ```
>    Name ID1 ID2 ID3
> 1:    A 101 102 103
> 2:    A 101 102 103
> 3:    B 201 202    
> 4:    C 301
> ```